# Why am I getting more rep points on Music.SE than other SE sites?

Tags: support, reputation

I seem to get 10 points per answer upvote on Music.SE, I'm sure the norm is 5 on other SE sites like stackoverflow. Is this a customisation for the site or because it's in beta, or perhaps something else?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure? I've always got 5 on questions...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it is like this. Check your stats on https://music.stackexchange.com/users/15313/mr-boy?tab=reputation&sort=post, they seem to show 5 per question upvote. For an answer upvote, 10 rep is granted.